# Growth rate of large sets

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose that ${a_k}$ is a real valued increasing sequence such that

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a_k} = +\infty ,$$

i.e. $\{a_1,a_2,\ldots\}$ is a [large set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_set_(combinatorics)).

If $\lim a_{k+1} - a_{k} = \infty$, what can be said about the rate of growth of $a_{k+1} - a_{k}$? It is true that

$$ \lim \frac{k}{a_{k+1} - a_{k}} = \infty ?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not true take $a_k =\ln k^k $

Comment: Thanks for the clever example. Do you think there is also an example of this kind of sequence that also has gaps that grow faster than exponential, i.e. $\lim \frac{a_{k+1} - a_{k}}{e^{k}} = \infty$?

Comment: @shamisen No, because then it would converge by comparison tests.